# How to do this custom label on Android?

Tags: android, textview, label

How the ways that I can make this custom Label?

[image]

Is it a TextView with a background image?

Comment: It could be a TextView with a background or a Button, too.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be needing a Custom View to create this.

Use a TextView with a background image and a Right Image property. Use RelativeLayout to overlap it over the coffee image.

In case you have to use it in more than one place extend a frameLayout to create a custom component.

Comment: overlapping can be done using frame layout as parent layout
add your text view last then set gravity according to your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be just a Imageview above another ImageView (coffee), which is above the TextView below.
You can look at Android [layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [UI.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Or, it is just a mobile version of a web page, then you can look at html to find out how to do it.